# Finding the electric field as a function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

A system carries charge density $\rho = 0$ in the region $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} <a$ and $\rho = \frac{k}{(x^2+y^2)^4}$ in the region $a\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Find the electric field as a function of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

---

What I did was the following:

Let $r=x^2+y^2$, now we have that for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} <a$, $\rho =0$ therefore $Q_{in} = 0$ thus the electric is zero.

For $a\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we have that $$E(4\pi r^2)=\int^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_a\frac{k}{r^4}4\pi r^2dr = \ ...$$

I am wondering if I am on the right track?

---

For cylindrical coordinates would it be? $$E(2L\pi \phi)=\int^{\phi}_a \rho \frac{k}{\phi^8 \epsilon_0}\pi L \phi^2d\phi$$

Comment: This problem doesn't have spherical symmetry, so $4\pi r^2 dr$ definitely isn't the right integration measure. Hint: the symmetry is cylindrical.

Comment: @probably_someone will it then be the following, $$\phi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$E(4\pi \phi^2)=\int^{\phi}_a \rho \frac{k}{\phi^4 \epsilon_0}4\pi \phi^2 d\phi$$

Comment: Not quite. Where are you getting the factor of $4\pi\phi^2$ from?

Comment: @probably_someone oh i misread your comment will it then be for cylindrical symmetry  $$\phi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ $$E(2\pi \phi)L=\int^{\phi}_a \rho \frac{k}{\phi^4 \epsilon_0}2\pi \phi L d\phi$$

Comment: Yes, that's more like it.

Comment: @probably_someone ty! If you write your comment as an answer I can then accept it.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: @BenCrowell sure will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that there's no spherical symmetry (the problem was careful to write $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ rather than $r$ for a reason), so the integration measure $4\pi r^2 dr$, which is used for spherically-symmetric distributions, is incorrect. You should use the integration measure for cylindrical symmetry instead.

Comment: Actually wouldn't it be $$E(2L\pi \phi)=\int^{\phi}_a \rho \frac{k}{\phi^8 \epsilon_0}\pi L \phi^2d\phi$$ since $$\phi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$